# What is the reason for limiting the number of answers I can delete?

Tags: discussion

Today I learned that I can only delete five of my own answers in one day. Can anybody tell me the reasoning behind this limitation, or point me to a Meta-SE thread or article explaining it?

I don't think I need protection from own decisions, but someone in authority evidently believes that I do. My suspicion is that this policy resulted from someone worrying about my SE account being compromised. Am I right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main (perhaps only) reason is to prevent vandalism and/or users trying to "take their ball and go home" — i.e., users that just want to remove all their contributions (forgetting that they gave an irrevocable and perpetual license to SE) because they're fed up/upset with someone or something/had a bad day/etc.

The system prevents you from deleting anymore and also raises a moderator flag, alerting us to a possible vandalism. I think it is a good barrier — we've had users that tried to delete all their content and the flags helped us track down useful content and undelete it, and also have a conversation with the user to try and understand their reasons (if any).

---

In your case, I dismissed the system flag because it was quite clear that you were removing old and ignored/un-upvoted posts. I think some regular pruning is generally a good thing to do :)